# What is the different between Docker bundles and docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker 1.12 introduced the new concept of bundles. A new file format to describe a set of services.

My application is already deployed with *docker-compose*. I have a `docker-compose.yml` for each of my environments and I can quickly deploy my app just with a `docker-compose up`.

From what I understand of [this post](https://blog.docker.com/2016/06/docker-app-bundle/), *Docker bundles* is just a new way built-in Docker to do the same thing as docker-compose does as an external software.

Is that it ? What can I expect from *Docker bundles* that I won't have with *docker-compose* ?

Comment: Good question, and I don't feel any of the answers address this well. I still have no idea what advantages DAB  gives over docker-compose.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> A Dockerfile can be built into an image, and containers can be created
>   from that image.
>
> Similarly, a docker-compose.yml can be built into a distributed
>   application bundle(DAB), and stacks can be created from that bundle.
>
> In that sense, the bundle is a multi-services distributable image
>   format.

Source: https://docs.docker.com/v18.03/compose/bundles/

Comment: All the docker images etc will be part of dab itself.. You don't have to download those image files from network.

Comment: Really? I think that dab file is a json file with instructions how to create services.

Comment: I create bundle with "docker-compose bundle" and get only one text file in my directory. Is it correct?

Comment: It's been some time  I moved to kubernetes and I completely forgot what dab was. You are right, dab is just a json file. As per their old roadmap(https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26876) dab is introduced as a predecessor to bundles. DAB is the file format used internally to represent bundle and the bundle is the one which will contain everything within and it will be a binary.

Answer (score 3):

The main different is that docker bundle is oriented to be used this the new server side orchestration features it use the docker service internal flow.

docker compose has all logics client side because it the client (compose) that do different requests at the server (daemon).

For docker bundle all flow is managed by the engine.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of the fundamental difference between the two. Can you elaborate a bit more on the advantages of Docker bundles over docker-compose? Is it the end of docker-compose? When is one more suitable to use over the other?

Comment: Sorry but at the moment I haven't a clear image about the future of compose.. My current idea it's that dab could be dedicated at scale and orchestration because the service api at the moment works only in swarm mode, compose will be part of the stack but for local and develop uses.

At the moment this is my idea but I hope to make it better between few days.

Answer (score 0):

There are some features not available in DAB right now compared to docker-compose like links, volume mounting. The host ports mapped to container ports mapped in compose file do not have any relevance as Swarm assigns a port randomly to the service. You can verify it by

> docker service inspect nginx

Of course you can update the port of a service anytime, for instance

> docker service update --publish-add 8080:80 nginx